# Como cambiar el tipo y tamaño de letra por defecto de IDE ECLIPSE?

Tags: eclipse, fuentes

Nunca tuve la necesidad de esto, hasta que me entere que han creado un tipo de letra para programadores. [Lease aqui](https://www.genbeta.com/herramientas/han-disenado-una-tipografia-ideal-para-escribir-codigo-y-es-open-source)

Me gustaria usarla en el IDE ECLIPSE. Para visualizar el codigo fuente cada vez que programe  en cualquier lenguaje sea `PHP`, `JAVA`, `HTML`, `CSS`, `JS`, `ESQL`, etc.

En otras palabra, **necesito cambiar la fuente por defecto del IDE ECLIPSE**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontre esta Solución (La fuente por defecto esta en la opción `Basic/Text Font.`):

> Menu Window → Preferences → General → Appearance → Colors and fonts → Basic → Text Font.

Referencias:

- http://softwaresalariman.blogspot.pe/2008/09/change-default-text-font-in-eclipse.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064649/how-do-i-change-the-default-text-font-in-eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Para cambiar la fuente te vas a `Window` -> `General` -> `Appearance` -> `Colors and fonts` y ahí vas a la pestaña de Java/PHP/ la que sea, y al desplegar veras uno que pone X Editor text font, la seleccionas y le das al botón de editar de la derecha y ahí eliges la fuente.