# Cambiar el tipo de letra a comic sans en el editor de Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Necesito cambiar el tipo de letra por defecto que trae Visual Studio, quiero utilizar una mejor tipografía para programar como **comic sans**. Me pueden ayudar.

Yo sé que en eclipse si se puede cambiar, como dice esta pregunta [Como cambiar el tipo y tamaño de letra por defecto de IDE ECLIPSE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/102603/2027)

Comment: Que version de Visual estas usando?

Comment: @LuisFernando 2015 y 2017

Comment: En VS2010 te vas a Herramientas/Opciones/Fuentes y colores y allí cambias en el Editor de Texto la fuente de la letra, que por defecto es `Consolas` mira a ver si es así también en VS2015 y VS2017

Comment: @Marc: es basicamente lo mismo en todas las versiones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Elija **Herramientas --> Opciones.**

En la lista de opciones, elija **Entorno, Fuentes y colores.**

En la lista Mostrar configuración para, elija Fuente del entorno.

Alli te aprecen las fuentes y elige la que gustes.

**Comic Sans MS** se llama la que mencionas.

Answer (score 9):

Para cambiar el tipo de fuente en el editor de Visual Studio, desde el menú abrir la secuencia:

`Tools` (Herramientas) > `Options` (Opciones)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

seleccionar la sección `Environment` (Entorno) y el elemento `Fonts and Colors` (Fuentes y colores):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En el caso del código selecciona la opción "Plain Text" (texto plano), que sera usada en el código y posteriormente el tipo de fuente "Comic Sans MS"**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma podras usar la fuente **Comic Sans MS** que deseas usar para programar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: exelente aporte Jorge